# Need Help Creating a Multi-Step, Video-Guided Enrollment Site

Tags: plugins, themes, customization, design

I have a distinct idea, and the beginnings of some ideas of how to implement it, but I find myself already spiraling off into research tangents and side-paths that can't possibly be healthy, so I figured I'd admit my ignorance and ask for help.

I'd like to craft a website whose primary elements are one (or possibly more, if that's easier) videos guiding you through an enrollment process, and then one or more pages dedicated to holding forms and downloads related to said enrollment.

In essence, my original vision was a site with a guide video situated in the top-left or top-center, approximately 5 minutes long, that discusses the basic technical elements of enrollment along with some fuzzier stuff (e.g., important dates, information about the program, etc.). Below or beside that, there would be a multi-step "enroller"--e.g., a step to collect name/address/contact info, a page to download important documentation, a page to submit additional survey information, etc.

Since the video relates to all these steps, I'd like the video to remain static while the user steps through the enrollment process.

Furthermore, since there are several steps, I'd prefer the enrollment process to use a sort of (Previous Page) (Next Page) structure to keep the contents of each step simple--if they were all just listed out on a single "page," it would stretch too far vertically and draw the user away from the video.

Finally, I'd like the video playing and the enrollment procedure to operate independently from one another. If the user finishes one step of enrollment and goes to the next, I don't want the whole page to refresh, reloading the video and making the user lose their place. I suspect that judicious use of iframes will be key here, but since the video's going to be hosted on Youtube, I am unsure if that might complicate things.

Theme isn't very important, and I'm happy to get any number of plugins--even paid ones--to make it work. Since I've already gazed into a number of rabbit's holes with plugins and iframes and modifying PHP files, I figured it'd be wise to ask if there's a preexisting theme or template for this before I lose untold amounts of time learning everything from scratch, but the specifics of what I want are hard to search for. Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: I can't comment so I'm posting a question as an answer. Did you ever get this site working? I am imagining you used BuddyPress or something to allow login, that way your site can keep track of the person's progress and enrollment data? Also what form tool did you use? (So far I've tried Forminator which is impressive, but want to try Ninja and others.) Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there are a couple of important parts here.

One is the "Featured Video Plus" Plugin to nest your video up in the area normally reserved for Featured Images, which gives it a nice, static, and dependable placement.

Another is Squelch Tabs and Accordions or a similar AJAX-powered tabbing plugin, which enables multi-page data to be contained on a single, non-refreshing section of a WP Post or Page.

Finally, for the submissions, an AJAX-powered Contact Form (there are many) is key.

Using these in concert enables a single WP Page (or Post) that contains a playable video and then has tabs of useful information, submittable forms, and downloadable data (using the standard Media Gallery in WP or one of your own choosing).